Programming a database to review form responses
I am trying to make an application where you answer questions in a form and upon submission should be handed an ID and then have the responses show up in a database, where i can present those answers. I tried using formik and async-storage to do this but i cant seem to find a way to fetch and present responses in another page.
Does anyone have experience with this?
should i use some other API or component?
Excuse my bad terminology.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {ScrollView, Button, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, Image, ImageBackground, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import StartMenu from './StartMenu';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import HercaDatabaseScreen  from './HercaDatabaseScreen';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


export default function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [showStartMenu, setShowStartMenu] = useState(true);
  const [selectedAnswer1, setSelectedAnswer1] = useState(null);
  const [selectedAnswer2, setSelectedAnswer2] = useState(null);
  const [selectedAnswer3, setSelectedAnswer3] = useState(null);
  const [selectedAnswer4, setSelectedAnswer4] = useState(null);
  const [formResponses, setFormResponses] = useState([]);

  // Formik initialization
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      Chefnamn: '',
      Dittnamn: '',
    },
    onSubmit: handleSubmit,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStoredData();
  }, []);

  // Function to fetch stored data from AsyncStorage
  const fetchStoredData = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hercaResponses');
      if (jsonValue !== null) {
        // Parse the retrieved data into an array of objects
        const storedResponses = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
        setFormResponses(storedResponses);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching stored data:', error);
    }
  };

  // Handle form submission
  async function handleSubmit(values) {
    try {
      // Construct response object
      const newResponse = {
        name: values.Chefnamn,
        name2: values.Dittnamn,
        answer1: selectedAnswer1,
        answer2: selectedAnswer2,
        answer3: selectedAnswer3,
        answer4: selectedAnswer4,
      };

      // Store response in AsyncStorage
      const updatedResponses = [...formResponses, newResponse];
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('hercaResponses', JSON.stringify(updatedResponses));

      // Display success message
      Alert.alert(
        'Success',
        'Herca ID-001454 har skapats!',
        [
          {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')
          }
        ]
      );

      // Clear the form values after submission
      formik.resetForm();

      // Update the state to reflect the new response
      setFormResponses(updatedResponses);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
      console.error('Error storing response:', error);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'An error occurred while storing the response. Please try again.');
    }
  }

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  };

  const handleStartQuestions = () => {
    setShowStartMenu(false); // Hide start menu
  };

  const handleAboutHerca = () => {
    // Logic to navigate to about Herca screen or perform related action
  };

  const handleOpenHercaDatabase = () => {
    // Logic to open the Herca database
    console.log("Opening Herca database...");
  };

  const handleGoToStartMenu = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Bekräftelse',
      'Är du säker på att du vill gå tillbaka till startmenyn? Alla ändringar kommer att raderas. ',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => setShowStartMenu(true)
        }
      ]
    );
  };

  // Render function for each table row
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.tableRow}>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.name2}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.answer1}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.answer2}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.answer3}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{item.answer4}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loggedIn ? (
        <>
          {showStartMenu ? (
            <StartMenu
              onStartQuestions={handleStartQuestions}
              onAboutHerca={handleAboutHerca}
              onOpenHercaDatabase={handleOpenHercaDatabase}
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.headerContainer} onPress={handleGoToStartMenu}>
                <ImageBackground
                  source={require('./PIXNIO-291667-1000x562.jpg')}
                  style={styles.headerBackground}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={require('./volvo-logo.png')}
                    style={styles.logo}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                  />
                </ImageBackground>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.95, height: 1, marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20, opacity: 0.1, backgroundColor: 'black' }} />
              </View>

              {/* Formik Form */}
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={formik.handleChange('Chefnamn')}
                value={formik.values.Chefnamn}
                placeholder="Ange Chef/Lagledares namn"
              />

              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={formik.handleChange('Dittnamn')}
                value={formik.values.Dittnamn}
                placeholder="Ange Operatörens namn"
              />
              {/* End of Formik Form */}

              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.95, height: 1, marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20, opacity: 0.1, backgroundColor: 'black' }} />
              </View>

              <Text style={styles.question}>Datum för inrapportering av Herca</Text>

              {/* DatePicker component goes here */}

              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.95, height: 1, marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20, opacity: 0.1, backgroundColor: 'black' }} />
              </View>

              <View style={styles.questionContainer}>
                <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
                  <Text style={styles.question}>Vet operatören hur arbetet ska utföras?</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedAnswer1}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedAnswer1(itemValue)}
                    style={styles.dropdown}
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="Nej" value="nej" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Delvis" value="delvis" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Ja" value="ja" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
                  <Text style={styles.question}>Hur vet operatören om arbetet är korrekt utfört?</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedAnswer2}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedAnswer2(itemValue)}
                    style={styles.dropdown}
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="SOP/OPL" value="Kontroll med SOP/OPL" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Egen kontroll" value="Egen kontroll" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Annat" value="Annat" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
                  <Text style={styles.question}>Hur vet operatören om arbetet är felfritt?</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedAnswer3}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedAnswer3(itemValue)}
                    style={styles.dropdown}
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="Nej" value="nej" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Delvis" value="delvis" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Ja" value="ja" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
                  <Text style={styles.question}>Vad gör operatören om problem uppstår?</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedAnswer4}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedAnswer4(itemValue)}
                    style={styles.dropdown}
                  >
                    <Picker.Item label="Tillkallar lagledare" value="Lagledare" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Egen kontroll" value="Egen kontroll" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Annat" value="Annat" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>
              </View>

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Skicka</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              {/* Display Form Responses */}
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Form Responses</Text>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FlatList
                  data={formResponses}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
              </View>
            </>

          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <LoginPage onLogin={handleLogin} />
      )}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

I tried to send form data from my app.js to another .js. I expected there to be an easy way to collect data from a form to present it.
